# jquery code redirect page according to visitor ip

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, ip

I have [www.propertyhere.com](http://www.propertyhere.com)

I want to insert some Jquery code in the index page to redirect visitor into the following pages according to their geographical ip location.

```
 if user ip is from AU then show:
 http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/AU/search-to-buy;

 if user ip is from CA then show:
 http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/CA/search-to-buy;

 if user ip is from NZ then show:
 http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/NZ/search-to-buy;

 if user ip is from US then show:
 http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/US/search-to-buy;

 if user ip is from CN then show:
 http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/CN/search-to-buy;

 if user ip is from RU then show:
 http://www.propertyhere.com/Country/RU/search-to-buy;
```

If visitor's ip doesn't match the above locations then just let the visitor stay in the homepage.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to do this client-side?  I would strongly recommend doing this server-side, and redirecting with the appropriate 301/302 status code and a `Location` header.  Besides, you'll need something server-side to figure out the network address anyway.

Comment: Do you have a service to find the location based on the ip address? If not you will need one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a service such as http://geoiplookup.wikimedia.org/ and do a simple ajax request.
This should grant you all the necessary details.

dome thing like this may help:

```
$.ajax('http://geoiplookup.wikimedia.org/', {
    crossDomain:true,
    success:function(data,text,xhqr){
        alert(data);
    },
    error:function(xhr, textStatus){
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: could you provide a JSFiddle of this solution working within the context of the question? I am trying to understand the answer but can't seem to know how to apply it to show for the scenario of different locations. IF ip USA then ELSE IF ip CN then etc etc thanks

Comment: No because JSFiddle prevent AJAX request from being used ... the `data` that is returend form the request to http://geoiplookup.wikimedia.org/ is in JSON format..

Comment: ok thanks. So is there any chance you could maybe post a piece of code that might not work on JSFiddle but I can get a clearer context how to execute. I see the alerts you are returning, but am still unsure where the IF statements fit in to the overall answer. Any help appreciated